# WHERE IN - must meet all params

Tags: mysql

I'm conducting a Where In Query.

Here's my query:

```
select * from `xh_user` 
where (select count(*) 
       from `xh_roles` 
       inner join `xh_role_user` on `xh_roles`.`id` = `xh_role_user`.`role_id` 
       where `xh_role_user`.`user_id` = `xh_user`.`id` 
       and `title` in (?, ?)) >= 1 
and `id` = ? limit 1'
```

I'm searching for rows where the title meets my params.

Rows come back if one of the params is met.

How can i make it so that all params must be met?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have two parameters:

```
select *
from `xh_user` 
where (select count(distinct title) 
       from `xh_roles` inner join
            `xh_role_user`
            on `xh_roles`.`id` = `xh_role_user`.`role_id` 
       where `xh_role_user`.`user_id` = `xh_user`.`id` and
             `title` in (?, ?)
      ) = 2 and
      `id` = ?
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with joins - adding a new join condition per parameter:

```
select * 
from `xh_user` 
inner join `xh_role_user`.`user_id` = `xh_user`.`id` 
inner join `xh_roles` as roles on roles.`id` = `xh_role_user`.`role_id` 
                               and title = ? --first title
inner join `xh_roles` as roles2 on roles2.`id` = `xh_role_user`.`role_id` 
                                and title = ? --second title
```